# Gson serialize interface / abstract class

Tags: java, gson, serialization

If I register a `JsonSerializer` with an **interface** or **abstract class** like:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(MyInterface.class, new MySerializer());
Gson gson = builder.create();

MyInterface i = new MyConcreteClass();
String json = gson.toJson(i); // <--- Serializer is not invoked
```

The serializer is simply not invoked in `gson.toJson()`.

However, if I have a class that contains `MyInterface`:

```
public class MyAnotherClass {
    MyInterface i;
    // ...
}

MyAnotherClass c = new MyAnotherClass()
String json = gson.toJson(c); // <--- Serializer is invoked
```

The serializer is invoked.

To me, this is kind of inconsistent behavior. The way it works on member variable is to look for the *declared* type instead of *actual* type, but the way it works on the "root" object is different.

Is this a bug / defect or an expected behavior? If this is expected, any reason behind?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is an expected behaviour. Gson has a list of default `TypeAdapterFactory` objects to use. You can see them in the [source of the Gson class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.3.1/com/google/gson/Gson.java?av=f#195).

There are adapters for `String`, `Number`, `Map`, `Collection`... The last one is important and is used when no adapters can handle a type: it is the `ReflectiveTypeAdapter`. This one retrieves by reflection all the fields of the object to serialize, and searches for the appropriate adapters to serialize the values of the fields.

So when Gson has to serialize an object, first it tries to find an adapter by using the actual type of the object. If the adapter found is not the `ReflectiveTypeAdapter`, it uses it. Otherwise it searches an adapter with the declarative type and uses it if it's not the `ReflectiveTypeAdapter`. Otherwise it uses the `ReflectiveTypeAdapter` on the object (you can look at the source of the class [TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.3.1/com/google/gson/internal/bind/TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java?av=f#46) to have more details on this mecanism). That's the behaviour you have with your attribute `MyInterface i`.

When you do:

```
MyInterface i = new MyConcreteClass();
String json = gson.toJson(i);
```

Gson tries to find an adapter for the type `MyConcreteClass` and it finds the `ReflectiveTypeAdapter`. So now it should search for an adapter with the declarative type. But it has no way to know the declarative type because no object references it, this is the root object. You know in your code that you want to use the type `MyInterface`, but Gson has not this information and has only the object instance. You may think that Gson could see that the object implements `MyInterface`, but that's not the way it works (and what to do if the object implements two interfaces?)

So, you have two ways to solve your problem:

1) When you call `Gson.toJson`, you can give the declarative type for the root object: [Gson#toJson(Object, Type)](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.reflect.Type))

```
String json = gson.toJson(i, MyInterface.class);
```

2) When you register your adapter, you can indicate that this adapter applies to all the subclasses: [GsonBuilder#registerTypeHierarchyTree](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object))

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(MyInterface.class, new MySerializer());
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still, I think it is an expected *defect* due to the limitation of Java.

Comment: When I use
    registerTypeHierarchyAdapter I'm stuck in a continuous loop when the serialize method executes result.add("properties", context.serialize(src, src.getClass()))

Comment: I tried your 1st solution and it gives me empty json {}